# How to specify which display i3-lock starts showing the image on?

Tags: i3, lock

I sometimes use a monitor with my laptop. I use `i3lock -t -i /path` as my locking command and the image I use is of the resolution of my laptop screen. Running this with the monitor connected the puts the initial image on the monitor screen, which is bigger, and then tiles it over to my screen (which is below the monitor). I want it to start tiling it on the laptop screen, so that the image appears properly on my primary screen, and then continue tiling it to the monitor.